# Is there a difference between uploading from file vs an in memory UIImage?

Tags: swift, upload, awss3transfermanager

I'm trying to upload a file from UIImagePickerController. Is it better to upload an image from memory or save it to disk then upload to S3

Which takes less resources? Currently weaker devices like an iPhone 5 struggles to upload the file.

Comment: BTW, for the sake of efficiency, if uploading the full resolution image, make sure to get the `NSData` for the underlying asset directly and upload that rather than getting the `UIImage` and then converting that to a `NSData` with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation`. Or if you don't need full resolution, resize it (and or request smaller `targetSize`), and upload that, as that may be considerably smaller. Personally, I'd suggest saving it to disk and uploading from that, to minimize how long you keep the full resolution data in memory (esp if uploading multiple files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that older devices have lower cellular speeds. There should not be any significant difference in WiFi speeds between iPhone 5 and newer models.

Since it is the uplink speed that is the problem, it makes no difference whether you are sourcing your image from memory or disk.  Moving an image from memory to disk and then back to memory before uploading has no advantages except for the fact that only parts of the image *maybe* kept in memory waiting for upload.

Comment: Ah I see. Occasionally I saw that the app was terminating due to memory pressure. I wondered how apps like WhatsApp and instagram dealt with this problem so efficiently...

Comment: Memory pressure termination is a different issue. I would keep the image in memory. That is your user's primary focus. I bet there are other images, resources that can be temporarily saved to disk or purged to relieve that problem.